# ERROR The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

My Windows Server 2008 RC 2 hard drive just died. Server was acting as domain controller and DNS for my company (it's small, less than 10 PCs).

I reinstalled WinServer 2008 on a new hard drive, named the server the same name, created the same users with the same passwords, etc.. When a user tries to log in on their computer with their domain account it says:

```
The security database on the server does not have a computer account 
for this workstation trust relationship
```

Is there *any* way I can modify something on the server to allow me to fix this? I don't want to recreate the accounts in every PC and have them rejoin the domain. This is a small server, domain is mostly used to share files and folders between PCs.

Comment: Was this the only domain controller?

Comment: Unfortunately, you screwed the pooch. What you have now is a brand new AD domain. You'll need to join all of the clients to the new domain and create user accounts for all of your users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to recreate the accounts and rejoin the PC's to the domain.  What you did was effectively start over.  You should have restored a backup of the DC properly: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc535164.aspx

If you still have a backup of the old server, it would be wise to look at restoring it properly, especially if it was also a file server.  But it's up to you...with a small shop you could look at just recreating things and rejoining computers.

Comment: Say I have a PC with two accounts, PCNAME\LocalUser and DOMAINNAME\DomainUser. In c:\Users there's two folders, LocalUser and DomainUser. If I rejoin the domain with the same DomainUser name, will it use the same folder or will this create a new c:\Users\DOMAIN.DomainUser ?

Comment: No, it won't use the same user profile.

Comment: Ok, so my best bet is to remove all the stuff from Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc.. from the domain account folders, delete the user in the local machine, then rejoin the domain, then move the documents back, so I only have one folder for local user and one for domain user.

Comment: No...use Profwiz after the fact to change the SIDs and use the same local PC profiles as before (http://www.forensit.com/downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `spn`.

One or more of them may be dup or pointing to an old DNS/NETBIOS name.

```
setspn -T <yourdomain> -F -Q */*
```

delete the unneeded

```
setspn -D XXX/yyy <oldserver>
```

and add the new location

```
setspn -A XXX/yyy <newserver>
```